# equals java unexpected result

Tags: java

I just started learning Java and came across equals. After looking for the difference between equals and ==, I decided to practice it myself but I am not getting the expected results. here is the code:

```
public class Sandbox {

/**
 * @param args
 *
 */
private int a;
public void setAtta(int value){a=value;}
public int getAtta(){return a;}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Sandbox s = new Sandbox();
    s.setAtta(10);
    Sandbox s1 = new Sandbox();
    s1.setAtta(10);

    System.out.println(s==s1);//false- EXPECTED
    System.out.println(s.equals(s1));//false- I thought it should be true?


}

}
```

Comment: setter-getter name start start with small letter (g/s)

Comment: the first google result for "java .equals" explains it just fine: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html

Comment: Or http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2004/jw-0614-equals.html or http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html

Comment: @Abu - renamed the methods and the class. Now it's more readable :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Object.equals` in Java is equivalent to `==`, i.e. it tests reference equality. Since your `Sandbox` class (implicitly) extends `Object`, and you don't override `equals`, `s.equals(s1)` calls `Object.equals`.

To get the behaviour you want, add an `equals` method (override) to your class:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this == obj) return true;
    if(!(obj instanceof Sandbox)) return false;
    Sandbox that = (Sandbox)obj;
    return this.a == that.a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
equals() method in object class, just use == comparison behind the screen. So you got it      as false. So you need to override it and give your implementation as needed.

public boolean equals(Object o){
if(o instanceof SandBox){
    if(((SandBox)o).a==this.a){
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works:

`equals` is an `Object` class method that you can `override`.

In `String` class, it is already overridden.

If you want your code, to work, you have to define your own `equals` method code. Because, obviously, `Object` class's code is not valid for `sandbox` class.

The method signature for `equals` is:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

the difference between `==` and `equals` is that `==` checks equality in references and `equals` checks equality in value. tell me please, what is the value of an object? that is why the result is false. unless overridden the `equals` of `sandbox` will invoke the `equals` of the `Object` class. You should override the `equals` function to check equality between you custom objects.

Comment: Objects have a value: themselves. `equals` is simply a reference check inherited from `Object` unless overridden.

Comment: @nneonneo - this is not correct. `this` is a pointer to the current object but there is no field on the `Object` class that stores this reference.

Comment: I was considering the abstract notion of "value". The "value" of an object is itself, because there is no other meaning ascribed.

Comment: The meaning is that because `s` and `s1` are 2 different objects then the references are different so `==` is false obviously but also `equal` will be false because they are 2 different objects that have the same value for a certain field. there for `equal` will not help here unless its overridden in the `sandbox` class